# Eclipse TPTP: How do I profile a unit test?

Tags: eclipse, profiling, eclipse-tptp

When I profile a project, I get a perspective which is mostly empty but for a view called "Profiling Monitor". I can see that the profiler is working (status bar says something about number of bytes and events processed per second) but how do I display the timing results?

Double clicking on the nodes "Execution Time Analysis" or "Profiling" in the "Profiling Monitor" view doesn't do anything :-(

Comment: TPTP is an overengineered, unholy abomination. It's also being officially discontinued: http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/project_info/devplans/EclipseTPTPProjectPlan2010.htm

Comment: *YAY* ^_^ ... so what do I use instead?

Comment: What do you need? JProfiler seems okay for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to install the "[Agent Controller](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/downloads/4.7.0/documents/installguide/InstallGuide.html#install_agent_controller)"